# auditd: re/load of rules on reboot only

Tags: linux-audit

Is this possible to configure auditd system from the LAS, only in a way that the rules are loaded after a reboot of the system?

Currently the way it is, is that it needs a restart of the service through `systemctl restart auditd`, however, I would love to know if there is a way to make that un-effective until the next reboot?

I looked the web but seems the current config files has no option for such thing, any idea?